# printing to an AirPrint printer from Android

Tags: android, airprint

Has anyone heard of anyone having any success implementing Apple's new AirPrint protocol on Android?

From various descriptions, it appears to be a fairly simple protocol employing [Internet Printing Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol), bonjour and PDF:

http://www.finnie.org/2010/11/13/airprint-and-linux/

These technologies all appear to be possible to implement on Android, but I'm wondering if there are any likely stumbling blocks?

(I realise AirPrint only works with a handful of printers just now, and only 11 HPs as listed on [Apple's airprint page](http://www.apple.com/ipad/features/airprint.html), but it is presumably only a matter of time before it becomes much more widespread.)

Thanks!

Comment: Even though it might be formally correct to close the question the "message" seems clear: How can I print from Android to an AirPrint printer? - There is a high interest in this question so I kindly ask to reopen the question. I'd be happy to make the question better and provide an answer as well.