# AirPrint-like SDK for Android?

Tags: android, printing, airprint

Is there any AirPrint(-like) SDK for Android devices? The objective is to let Android apps to print to AirPrint-ready (or similar technology) printers, *without* the need of any PC/equipment between the Android device and the printer. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [printing to an AirPrint printer from Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293975/printing-to-an-airprint-printer-from-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has their own architecture for this that they're working on: [Cloud Print](http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/overview.html)

Dec 7, 2010 [blog entry](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/12/google-cloud-print-now-available.html) on Cloud Print.

Added: [Google page](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/p/cloudprint.html) for installing Cloud Print on your PC

Comment: Currently there exists exactly 0 printer models that don't need extra PC/equipment in order to use Google Cloud Print.