# Printing from Android over AirPrint?

Tags: android, printing, airprint, ipp-protocol

Is this possible? I checked out [printing to an AirPrint printer from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293975/printing-to-an-airprint-printer-from-android), but it was closed for "not being a question" (I don't really know why, it seemed like a legitimate question to me) and the only answer to it totally doesn't answer the question.

What I need is a way to print to a wireless printer on the same network (possibly intranet) via my Android device, using code. If there's no Android official SDK for it, is there a custom library anyone knows of or a possible workaround to it? Possibly using AirPrint; if PrintBot can do it, there's no reason why there shouldn't be a corresponding hack for it.

Comment: UPnP is a fairly simple solution, though I don't know the saturation of UPnP enabled printers vs AirPrint enabled. Both numbers looks fairly large.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to print to an AirPrint printer from Android.

There are a number of printer apps available that claim to support AirPrint.
As of my experience they don't work very well unfortunately.

In general it's a good idea to use the Android Print API. Job transmission and potential rendering should be done by appropriate printer drivers.

In case of AirPrint the driver could send a PDF straight to the printer. If you don't want to use Androids Printservice you can use my [ipp-client](https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin).

Comment: Can you please help me to connect AirPrint printers from Android devices?

Comment: The github documentation of my library should provide all you need. You can also create an issue if you have difficulties following the documentation or sample code.